# How I can select two elements to one list with linq

Tags: arrays, .net, linq, select, array-merge

Firstly I need to create string array that include elements came from  different properties of one object.

At the below code MyDatas is IEnumerable, prop1 and prop2 are string.

```
var array = myDatas.Select(md => md.prop1).ToArray();
array.Concat(myDatas.Select(md => md.prop2).ToArray());
```

and I will use this array for a method paramater.

I want make it simple and use like this;

```
Method(myDatas.Select(md=>md.prop1).......ToArray());
```

How will be second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass

```
myDatas.SelectMany(x => new[]{x.prop1, x.prop2}).ToArray()
```

Comment: Yeah, It provides thanks!